Can a system of non-black holes become a black hole?
As we know, the Schwarzschild radius and mass are proportional: $r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$. If the density of a substance is constant, the mass and radius of an object made of that substance are proportional to the cube. Therefore, if the radius of an object doubles, the Schwarzschild radius increases by a factor of 8. In other words, can a system made of multiple neutron stars rotating around each other become a black hole? Please let me know if I am wrong.
I thought that a black hole with a very large Schwarzschild radius could have a very low density. If you replace $M$ in the Schwarzschild radius formula with density, you get the Schwarzschild radius formula depending on the density: $r_s = \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{8.37Gρ}}$. If you substitute the density of water here, the Schwarzschild radius becomes $711334662 \,\text{km}$. So, a black hole with a radius of about 10000 times that of the sun doesn't have to have a very high density (the density of water). If we extend this size to the entire universe, our universe could be a black hole and there would be no need for a singularity. Please correct my foolish thinking.


I would recommend using MathJax by wrapping equations in dollar signs, $like this$. 2) Yes, if two neutron stars collide in such a way that the resultant object has a Schwarzschild radius larger than its physical radius, it would theoretically become a black hole (in reality it's much more complicated than that). 3) Water is extremely dense. A density of one ton per cubic meter is about thirty-two orders of magnitude greater than the observed density of about 5.9 protons per cubic meter. The Universe is probably not a black hole.


See also this very similar question which points out that supermassive black holes have an average density less than water's, and whose answers point out that the idea that we are "inside a black hole Universe", perpetuated by pop science without much actual explanation, actually refers to the idea that we are surrounded by a cosmological horizon due to the Universe's expansion that makes us inside an "inside-out" black hole, sans singularity. Also, SMBHs (like Sagit. A*) are only a few dozen times our Sun's size.

What I'm trying to say is not after the neutron stars collide, but before they collide.
Generally, when we think of black holes, we always think of the density as being very high and that there is a singularity.
If a system of neutron stars can become a black hole, there is no need to introduce the concept of a singularity.
That is, what I'm trying to say is

The density of a black hole can be very small.
If a system of objects other than black holes can become a black hole, there is no need to introduce a singularity.
I look forward to more explanations.


In principle, sure. A quick Google search reveals this. Although I think necessarily the density of a black hole must be large; the density of Sag. A* is over 1,000 tons per cubic meter, and it is 0.08 AU in radius. Either way, once the black hole forms, the information about what came before is lost; a black hole is entirely characterized by its mass, charges, and angular momentum, and by nothing else, and standard solutions (i.e. Schwarzschild, Kerr, KN, KNdS) all contain singularities of some kind somewhere.

I think the concept of information disappearing is when observed from outside a black hole.
We have thought that black holes have infinitely high density, have a singularity, and that the laws of physics are destroyed at their center.
However, if a black hole can exist even with a low density, or if a system made of objects other than black holes can exist as a black hole, I think that the gravity of the black hole might not be strong enough to destroy the nuclear force, and that the gravity at the center of the black hole might be canceled and become zero.

Black holes do not have a density to begin with. There is an imaginary event horizon IN VACUUM from below which matter can not return (and another horizon for light). At the horizon the density is zero. The density stays zero for a long time after that. Then comes a giant wave of radiation and IF one could go through that, then we would either find ourselves in a very high density region inside the black hole about which we know absolutely nothing OR back in an empty universe because the black hole would have evaporated underneath our (very hot) feet, i.e. we would evaporate ourselves.

@spangmaed Your question is based on a popular misconception on what the “Schwarzschild radius” is. It is the circumference of the horizon divided by $2\pi$. The actual radius of any black hole defined as the spacelike radial distance from the horizon to the origin is zero according to the Schwarzschild metric. The volume inside the horizon (as we observe from outside) is also zero. Regardless of how much water you put together, it won’t form a black hole without first going into a gravitational collapse. Also note that all mass is outside the horizon, so your “density” formula is moot anyway.

I think you are imagining that the density of matter that goes into forming a BH is what causes the singularity.  But what causes the singularity is that for any point in spacetime inside the event horizon, any trajectory whatsoever must point radially inward.  The radial direction becomes timelike, and no material object at that point could continue at its current radius without moving inward – any more than right now you could remain at 12:00 pm without progressing to 12:01, and later to 1:00 pm.
Extended matter cannot exist in this type of spacetime (at least matter as we currently understand it), because in order to be "extended" it would have to exist at various radial locations indefinitely.  Inside a Black Hole, all matter and light have a destination: the center.  And all will inexorably reach it.  This point, if it were to exist, would be where everything that ever existed in the BH now resides, colocated, at $r=0$.  So we inelegantly say that point would be "infinitely dense."
In reality though, it is nearly certain that general relativity and our current understanding of matter fail inside a BH, so you should take this description of a singularity lightly. It is as if we made a very accurate simulation of the universe in a virtual reality like a video game, and most everything matched the real world extremely well, but suddenly you opened a door and just saw
00010111111000111
00011110100010001
#ERROR
inside.
That doesn't mean the real world looks like that. It means our code crashed under those conditions, and we need a better code engine to simulate the contents of that room.
It's currently under development, but progress is slow.

To simplify this answer and several comments: the Schwarzschild radius isn't (technically) the distance at which light cannot escape (although that is also true), it is the distance from the black hole at which the current understandings of the way space and time and matter work.

I can't exactly agree with that. The structure at $r<r_s$ is well understood in General Relativity (albeit unproven by observations).  It is at $r=0$, or close to it, that the theory diverges and likely becomes unphysical

@RC_13 The theory also diverges at $r=r_s$, even if the interior of the black hole itself makes sense - see the $g_{rr}$ component in spherical coordinates and note the divison by zero.

But that problem is specific to Schwarzschild coordinates or similar coordinates. A falling observer sees no problem at $r=r_s$. All observers see a singularity at $r=0$
